# LE Set Data Length returns Unsupported Feature or Parameter Value

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I setup a gatt-server on samsung platform (using bluez 5.47), upon client connect I want to configure the data length (this sets the link layer packet length)
which will return Unsupported Feature or Parameter Value.

the same command works when I setup a client that connects to a remote gatt-server. 
* according to bluetooth core spec 4.2 I should be able to do that 
"Both the master and slave can initiate this procedure at any time after entering the Connection State".
* I tried to enter some default values of tx octet 27, tx time 328, this does not work. (probably means this isn't parameter value issue). 
anyone know why is that not working?
* just to be noted, I would like this to be set in order to increase throughput. currently set MTU and connection params only.

< HCI Command: LE Set Data Length (0x08|0x0022) plen 6                                                                                                                            #31973 [hci0] 5281.478803
        Handle: 1894
        TX octets: 251
        TX time: 2120

> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 6                                                                                                                                       #31974 [hci0] 5281.479176
>         LE Set Data Length (0x08|0x0022) ncmd 1
>           Status: Unsupported Feature or Parameter Value (0x11)
>           Handle: 1894

Answer (score 0):

turnes out I connected to Ipone 6s which does not support bluetooth 4.2 (it supports bluetooth 4.1). That was the reason for "Unsupported Feature" 
Meaning both master and slave must support bluetooth 4.2 (since data length extension is feature of bluetooth 4.2)